# Moving Average using SQL in Python

Tags: sql, sqlite, window-functions, moving-average

`c.execute (''' SELECT avg(close) OVER(ORDER BY date Rows Between 10 Preceding and Current row) as MovingAvg FROM database WHERE ticker in ('AAPL') ''' )`

**OperationalError: near "OVER": syntax error**

When I use the same line in DB Browser for SQLite it works perfectly fine but when I try to use it in python I have this error

Comment: Are you running the queries against the same database? What is the version of the SQLite database that you are running the query against in Python, and in DB Browser?

Comment: I use DB browser only to visualise the data it’s not part of the project.it’s python 3 and SQLite3. Yes it’s the same database, the same table . Sorry I m not sure i fully answer your question.

Comment: Well if that's again the same database and it works in DB Browser, you should not be getting that SQL error in python...

Comment: The version of sqlite your python setup is using is too old to support window functions. needs to be using 3.25 or newer.

Comment: Thank you that was the reason , I was using Colab and SQLite was in 3.22.0, I switched  to Jupyter Notebook and it works perfectly.